# Is Crypto-JS AES library still considered secure?

Tags: encryption, javascript, aes, library

My company has to send out passwords to employees. We want to do so by using the Crypto-JS AES library to locally create the encrypted message and then send the encrypted message to the employee so that they can locally decrypt the message.

However, I noticed that the Crypto-JS project seems to have been abandoned and there haven't been any changes since 2013. Is their AES library still considered secure to use in Javascript or is there another encryption library for Javascript that should be used instead?

Comment: Huh?  Which specific project are you looking at?

I see https://github.com/brix/crypto-js (the one referred to from https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) and it's last release is in February 2017 and the last commit was in June.  Admittedly, I see a number of open issues so I don't think the maintenance is great, but it's not 2013 bad.

You also might find https://tonyarcieri.com/whats-wrong-with-webcrypto of interest

Comment: @Swashbuckler I am referring to [Jeff Mott's Crypto-JS](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/)

Comment: Another option, which is also actively maintained, is the [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl).